# (Jython) Problems to run python script from java

Tags: java, python, jython

I wrote 2 python scripts named runner.py and connect.py.
The runner script starts a traffic simulation with a specific port and the other one connects and is able to send commands. Both scripts work fine in my python IDE. But i want to start both scripts from java to recieve data.

```
import org.python.core.PyInstance;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.core.PyString;

public class PythonHandler {

    PythonInterpreter interpreter = null;
    String script_dir;

    public PythonHandler() {
        PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), new String[0]);

        this.interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        this.script_dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    }

    void execfile(final String fileName) {
        this.interpreter.execfile(fileName);
    }

    PyInstance createClass(final String className, final String opts) {
        return (PyInstance) this.interpreter.eval(className + "(" + opts + ")");
    }

    /**
     * This method will start the python script runner.py
     * NOTE: doesn't work if there is not a main method in the python script
     */
    public void startRunner() {
        String runner_dir = script_dir + "\\src\\de\\uniol\\inf\\is\\odysseus\\pgtaxi\\traci\\traci4python\\runner.py";
        PythonHandler ie = new PythonHandler();
        ie.execfile(runner_dir);
    }

    /**
     * This method will start the python script connect.py
     * NOTE: doesn't work if there is not a main method in the python script
     */
    public void startConnect() {
        String connect_dir = script_dir
                + "\\src\\de\\uniol\\inf\\is\\odysseus\\pgtaxi\\traci\\traci4python\\connect.py";
        PythonHandler ie = new PythonHandler();
        ie.execfile(connect_dir);
    }

    /**
     * This method will start the python script connect.py 
     * If there is not a main method you can run a specific function
     * 
     * @param function
     *            name of the function you want to start
     */
    public void callConnectFunction(String function) {
        String connect_dir = script_dir
                + "\\src\\de\\uniol\\inf\\is\\odysseus\\pgtaxi\\traci\\traci4python\\connect.py";
        PythonHandler ie = new PythonHandler();
        ie.execfile(connect_dir);
        PyInstance run = ie.createClass("Connection", "None");
        run.invoke(function);
    }

    /**
     * This method will start the python script runner.py
     * If there is not a main method you can run a specific function
     * 
     * @param function
     *            name of the function you want to start
     */
    public void callRunnerFunction(String function) {
        String runner_dir = script_dir + "\\src\\de\\uniol\\inf\\is\\odysseus\\pgtaxi\\traci\\traci4python\\connect.py";
        PythonHandler ie = new PythonHandler();
        ie.execfile(runner_dir);
        PyInstance run = ie.createClass("Runner", "None");
        run.invoke(function);
    }
}
```

Both scripts start but in the connect.py occur an error. I don't unterstand why i'm able to run the script from the python IDE but not from my java code.
Here are the code from the python scripts:

runner.py

```
import sys
import subprocess
import os

PORT = 8873

class Runner:  
__gui = None

def __init__(self, gui):
    self.__gui = gui
    print "Starting runner..."

def runLocal(self):
    sumoBinary = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
    sumoBinary = sumoBinary.split('de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi')[0]
    sumoBinary = sumoBinary + 'de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi\\sumo\\bin\\sumo-gui'
    scenario = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
    scenario = sumoBinary.split('de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi')[0]
    scenario = scenario + 'de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi\\scenario\\oldenburg.sumocfg'
    sumoProcess = subprocess.Popen([sumoBinary, "-c", scenario, "--remote-port", str(PORT)], stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
conn = Runner('None')
conn.runLocal()
```

connect.py

```
import sys
import os

PORT = 8873

class Connection:
__gui = None

def __init__(self, gui):
    self.__gui = gui
    print "Starting connect..."

def initTraci(self):
    tools = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
    tools = tools.split('de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi')[0]
    tools = tools + 'de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi\\sumo\\tools'
    sys.path.append(tools)
    import traci
    traci.init(PORT)
    step = 0
    while step < 1000:   
        traci.simulationStep()
        step += 1

    traci.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()

def getFreePort(self):
    tools = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
    tools = tools.split('de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi')[0]
    tools = tools + 'de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi\\sumo\\tools'
    sys.path.append(tools)
    import sumolib
    PORT = sumolib.miscutils.getFreeSocketPort()

if __name__ == '__main__':
conn = Connection('None')
conn.initTraci()
```

I get this Exception:

```
 Exception in thread "MainThread" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FEPREUSS\Desktop\PG\workspace\de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi\src\de\uniol\inf\is\odysseus\pgtaxi\traci\traci4python\connect.py", line 44, in <module>
    conn.initTraci()
  File "C:\Users\FEPREUSS\Desktop\PG\workspace\de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi\src\de\uniol\inf\is\odysseus\pgtaxi\traci\traci4python\connect.py", line 25, in initTraci
    traci.init(PORT)
  File "C:\Users\FEPREUSS\Desktop\PG\workspace\de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi\sumo\tools\traci\__init__.py", line 65, in init
    return getVersion()
  File "C:\Users\FEPREUSS\Desktop\PG\workspace\de.uniol.inf.is.odysseus.pgtaxi\sumo\tools\traci\__init__.py", line 82, in getVersion
    return _connections[""].getVersion()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getVersion'
```

And the two methods from the lib who cause the excpetion:

```
def init(port=8813, numRetries=10, host="localhost", label="default"):
    """
    Establish a connection to a TraCI-Server and store it under the given
    label. This method is not thread-safe. It accesses the connection
    pool concurrently.
    """
    _connections[label] = connect(port, numRetries, host)
    switch(label)
    return getVersion()

def getVersion():
    return _connections[""].getVersion()
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: The error message indicates that the connection to SUMO failed. It is a confusing message and there is already a ticket to address this http://sumo.dlr.de/trac.wsgi/ticket/2444. Can you add the precise jython calls you did to the question and check whether sumo is really started by runner.py (shows up in the process list).

Comment: I added the full class for the jython connection. Sumo is really started. Also i tried to connect to a Sumo application which is running on a server and i got the same error message.

Comment: How do you make sure that sumo is already up and listening when you try to connect? Did you try to connect after some delay?

Comment: I tried a delay between the execution of the scripts. But i still get the same exception. Furthermore the server connection where Sumo is definitely running failed with Jython.

Comment: Does the Python IDE use Jython or CPython? What happens if you use CPython or Jython from the command line?

Comment: The Python IDE uses CPython. I just implemented the Jython jar library in my Java project. If i run my python scripts from the command line they also work.

Comment: Okay now i created a new Jython instead of a Python project in my Python IDE, copied my scripts in the project and start them as Jython run. The runner works fine, but the connect script results in the same exception as i  run the script from Java.

Comment: OK, did you try jython from the command line as well? And which versions / platform are you on? Just tried jython here with the traci_tls tutorial but apparently my jython is very outdated.

Comment: I don't know why, but i'm not able to run my script with jython on the command line. I'm using jython2.7.0 as installer (also tried the standalone version). My OS is Windows 7 and i'm using Eclipse with the Python Plugin .

Comment: Now i have tested the traci_tls tutorial in Jython and i get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stumbled on a [jython bug](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2273) which was masked away by SUMO hiding the error message of the failed socket connection. Unfortunately you can not work around it easily other than editing SUMO/tools/traci/connection.py in line 49.

Just replace `self._socket = socket()` with

```
self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
```

A workaround was committed to the SUMO repository as well.